# Rendering KML file on QGIS with original resolution?

Tags: qgis, raster, kml, google-earth

I am trying to upload to QGIS a KML raster file that was previously generated with Google Earth Pro. It uploads, yes, but with low resolution.

How can I make QGIS render such files with the original resolution?

Comment: Can you share the KML file for testing?

Comment: I've just figured out what could have happened. QGIS only displays the first "layer" of the KML file. Maybe it has to do with the way the KML file is laid out.